# iOS - How to draw a transparent triangle in view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-graphics

I am trying to do a custom tab bar with a transparent triangle that points into the tab bar's view.

Right now I am drawing a linear gradient and a gloss in the drawRect method for the background of this tab bar. I just need to add the transparent triangle on there. I know how to draw a triangle. I just need to know how to make it transparent to show the background beneath the tab bar view.

Anyone know how to do this?

**Update**

Here is the current code:

```
void drawGlossAndGradient(CGContextRef context, CGRect rect, CGColorRef startColor, CGColorRef endColor) 
{    
    drawLinearGradient(context, rect, startColor, endColor);

    CGColorRef glossColor1 = [UIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:1.0 
                                          blue:1.0 alpha:0.35].CGColor;
    CGColorRef glossColor2 = [UIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:1.0 
                                          blue:1.0 alpha:0.1].CGColor;

    CGRect topHalf = CGRectMake(rect.origin.x, rect.origin.y, 
                            rect.size.width, rect.size.height/2);

    drawLinearGradient(context, topHalf, glossColor1, glossColor2);

}

void drawLinearGradient(CGContextRef context, CGRect rect, CGColorRef startColor, CGColorRef  endColor) 
{
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGFloat locations[] = { 0.0, 1.0 };

    NSArray *colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(__bridge id)startColor, (__bridge id)endColor, nil];

    CGGradientRef gradient = CGGradientCreateWithColors(colorSpace, (__bridge CFArrayRef) colors, locations);

    CGPoint startPoint = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(rect), CGRectGetMinY(rect));
    CGPoint endPoint = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(rect), CGRectGetMaxY(rect));

    CGContextSaveGState(context);
    CGContextAddRect(context, rect);
    CGContextClip(context);
    CGContextDrawLinearGradient(context, gradient, startPoint, endPoint, 0);
    CGContextRestoreGState(context);

    CGGradientRelease(gradient);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace); 
}
- (void)drawTriangle
{
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGPoint pt1 = CGPointMake(0.0f, 0.0f);
    CGPoint pt2 = CGPointMake(10.0f, 10.0f);
    CGPoint pt3 = CGPointMake(20.0f, 0.0f);

    CGPoint vertices[] = {pt1, pt2, pt3, pt1};

    CGContextBeginPath(context);
    CGContextAddLines(context, vertices, 3);
    CGContextClosePath(context);
    CGContextClip(context);
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();    


    CGColorRef lightColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:65.0f/255.0f green:64.0f/255.0f 
                                         blue:66.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0].CGColor;
    CGColorRef darkColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:37.0/255.0 green:31.0/255.0 
                                        blue:32.0/255.0 alpha:1.0].CGColor;

    [self drawTriangle];

    CGRect viewRect = self.bounds;

    drawGlossAndGradient(context, viewRect, lightColor, darkColor); 
}
```

I added the clip suggested below but that just made my background with the gradient and the gloss dissappear and the triangle become gray. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Some code would be useful to help you out > `I know how to draw a triangle.` -> so post it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you draw this gradient in drawRect: method just add clipping path before it.

Example:

```
-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
  CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
  CGPoint vertices[] = {coordinates of vertices};

  CGContextBeginPath(ctx);
  CGContextAddLines(ctx, vertices, sizeof(vertices)/sizeof(CGPoint));
  CGContextClosePath(ctx);
  CGContextClip(ctx);

  // draw the gradient
}
```

Vertices - is an array with 7 points. 1 point per each corner of self.bounds and 3 points which are define the triangle.

For example:

```
   (0)  (1)  (3)           (4)
     _____   ________________
    |     \ /               |
    |      V                |
    |     (2)               |
(6) |_______________________|(5)

CGPoint vertices[7] = {CGPointZero, // origin
                       p1, p2, p3, // vertices of the triangle
                       {self.bounds.size.width, 0},
                       {self.bounds.size.width, self.bounds.size.height},
                       {0, self.bounds.size.height}
}
```

Comment: I added the clip as you suggested but then it wouldn't draw my background and made the triangle gray ??

Comment: Sorry, my fault. Of cause vertices should represent not the triangle but reverse area. Look my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

If anybody needs, this is a code to draw a colored triangle in a UITableView without using UIImageView. This method is good because, the size of triangle can vary and it is drawn programmatically. Also, you can probably change colors and make triangle transparent.

```
@implementation RRTriangleView

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {

      CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();
      CGPathMoveToPoint(path, NULL, 0.0, 0.0);
      CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, - self.bounds.size.height / 2.0, self.bounds.size.height / 2.0);
      CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 0.0, self.bounds.size.height);
      CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 0.0f, 0.0f);

      CAShapeLayer *shapeLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
      [shapeLayer setPath:path];
      [shapeLayer setFillColor:[COLOR_CUSTOM_LIGHT_BLUE CGColor]];
      [shapeLayer setStrokeColor:[COLOR_CUSTOM_LIGHT_BLUE CGColor]];
      [shapeLayer setPosition:CGPointMake(self.bounds.size.width, 0.0f)];
      [[self layer] addSublayer:shapeLayer];

      CGPathRelease(path);

    }
    return self;
}
```

Init this TriangleView and add it to your cell, when it is selected :

```
- (RRTriangleView *)triangleView
{
  if (! _triangleView) {

    _triangleView = [[RRTriangleView alloc] initWithFrame:self.bounds];
    _triangleView.layer.backgroundColor = [[UIColor clearColor] CGColor];
    _triangleView.clipsToBounds = NO;

  }

  return _triangleView;
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
  //[super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

  if (selected) {

    [self addSubview:self.triangleView];

  }
  else {

    [self.triangleView removeFromSuperview];

  }
}
```

The size of triangleView is like your cell's view, it is transparent and it is drawn above.

Answer (score -1):

I beleive that

```
[view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[view setOpaque:NO];
```

will make your view transparent.

Comment: The whole view does not need to be transparent... just the triangle drawn on the view.

Comment: I don't understand. You want to draw a triangle which is completely transparent?

Comment: Yes, on a view that has a black background. The view itself is not transparent. It is black. But behind this view is an image. I want to be able to see that image through that triangle. So just the triangle is completely transparent.

Comment: Ah, now I understand. You have to create a `CALayer` mask to do this, **or** it's also possible to use an image.

Comment: OK, so how do you use a CALayer mask to do it?